# How to generate a circular nodemap in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to generate a nodemap in the following manner?

The idea here is to fix the central node at the centre of the viewport and then create coordinates in a circular manner without overlapping and arrange each nodes to corresponding position. This is level 1.

Then we proceed to level two where each child nodes with children becomes level two. There also we generate coordinates in circular manner without overlapping and arrange those child nodes in level two.

Likewise we proceed to subsequent levels.

**NOTE** note that overlapping should be prevented and also minimum possible radius should be used for circular arrangement. (i.e. without any collision)

Each node has it's own dimensions (length and breadth)

This is what I've tried out

```
function getCircularAngles(points) {
  return [...Array(points).keys()].map(
    (num) => num * ((Math.PI * 2) / points)
  );
}

function getCoorByAngle(
  origin,
  angle,
  radius
) {
  return {
    x: origin.x + Math.sin(angle) * radius,
    y: origin.y + Math.cos(angle) * radius,
  };
}

function getCircularCoords(
  origin,
  points,
  radius
) {
  return getCircularAngles(points).map((angle) =>
    getCoorByAngle(origin, angle, radius)
  );
}
```

But this is not being able to generate the circular coordinates recursively.
(i.e. by traversing through the child nodes / connections) & also this is not preventing collisions.

**SO I need a better way to permute nodes without colliding in a circular manner recursively**

**I cant use any graphing libraries because the boxes I create are custom svg... I don't think 3rd party libraries are going to support custom svg elements.** Need an algorithm in vanilla js.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the best end result you may want to look into [force-directed graph drawing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing)  techniques. Basically you run a physics simulation on your graph and it just sorts itself out. Many libraries already do this, including the very popular [d3.js](https://d3js.org/) (which supports SVG, btw).

Otherwise, you can try doing exactly as you say: start laying out nodes level by level, pre-calculating the minimum radius required to avoid overlap. The problem comes when you've got a big graph. Let's say you have two adjacent nodes that both have a lot of children. You can push one of them out really far from the center so the children of each node don't touch, but a more ideal solution would have those two nodes at opposite sides of your graph. If you're wanting that you'll either need to use a force-directed graph, or else try many permutations and settle on the best one.

Comment: Yeah. I know d3.js but I'm creating custom svg.. which are dynamic i.e you can do other stuffs with it. So I need full control... this is possible only if I don't use any libraries.

Comment: it's kind of a whole project, but luckily one that's been done many times before. Here's one such [example](https://bl.ocks.org/heybignick/3faf257bbbbc7743bb72310d03b86ee8) I found.

Answer (score 0):

You might like to experiment with the `GraphViz` open-source language tool to see how it decides to plot your diagram.

GraphViz uses a *language* to describe relationships, then calculates a graph layout by various algorithms which they actually discuss at some length.  *(Could it be that you could* ***use*** *GraphViz to accomplish this task entirely?)*

[GraphViz web site](https://graphviz.org)

Comment: this has to be done in javascript. I can't use any libraries.

Comment: then you should use HTML5 canvas,  paired with CSS and JS due to your external library restriction, which is cumbersome.  Graphviz as @Mike Robinson answer,  is the lingua franca to paint any kind of graph,  works very well and is super lean.